# Conditionally running Slick statements in a for comprehension

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

Given the following Slick code:

```
   val doUpdate = true

   val table1 = TableQuery[Table1DB]
   val table2 = TableQuery[Table2DB]
   val table3 = TableQuery[Table3DB]

   val action = (for {
          _ <- table1.filter(_.id === id).update(table1Record)
          _ <- table2.filter(_.id === id).update(table2Record)
          _ <- table3.filter(_.id === id).update(table3Record)
     } yield ()).transactionally
```

What I need is to update `table2` and `table3` ONLY if the variable doUpdate is true. This is my attempt:

```
   val action = (for {
          _ <- table1.filter(_.id === id).update(table1Record)
          _ <- table2.filter(_.id === id).update(table2Record)
               if (doUpdate == true)
          _ <- table3.filter(_.id === id).update(table3Record)
               if (doUpdate == true)
     } yield ()).transactionally
```

This compiles, but when I run it I get the following error `Action.withFilter failed`. How to add the condition?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you notices if you use `if` inside a `for` it will call `withFilter` underneath. In case of pipelines (`DBIO`, `Future`s, `Task`s) that filtering boils down to whether or not continue with a pipeline (happy path) or fail it (generating `Failure` or similar).

If all you want is to update, then you can go with the `if` road and recover the `Future`. However, it would we ugly, since depending on how you write the `case` it might also recover from errors you would like to be informed about.

Alternative is to simply use if-else to provide a different `DBIOAction`:

```
(for {
  _ <- {
    if (doUpdate) conditionalAction.map(_ => ())
    else DBIOAction.successful(())
  }
} yield ()).transactionally
```

In your case it could look something like:

```
val action = (for {
  _ <- table1.filter(_.id === id).update(table1Record)
  _ <- {
    if (doUpdate) DBIOAction.seq(
      table2.filter(_.id === id).update(table2Record),
      table3.filter(_.id === id).update(table3Record)
    )
    else DBIOAction.successful(())
  }
} yield ()).transactionally
```